# Boolian check giving incorrect answer

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make a reputation system:

```
if($upvotetruedownvotefalse == false){
    if(strpos($lines[2],$username.",") !== false){
        echo "you've already downvoted";
    }
    else{
        echo "you haven't downvoted yet";
        $lines[2] = $username.",".$lines[2];
        $lines[0] = $lines[0]-1 . "\n";
        file_put_contents( $filename , $lines);

    }
}
if($upvotetruedownvotefalse == true){
    if(strpos($lines[1],$username.",") !== false){
        echo "you've already upvoted";
    }else{
        echo "you haven't upvoted yet";
        $lines[1] = $username.",".$lines[1];
        $lines[0] = $lines[0]+1 . "\n";
        file_put_contents( $filename , $lines);
    }

}
```

The value of  `$upvotetruedownvotefalse` is determined through AJAX

However these comparison operators is giving me wrong results.

For example if `$upvotetruedownvotefalse = false` then `$upvotetruedownvotefalse == true`would be triggered.
I've tested this by echoing the value of `$upvotetruedownvotefalse`and recieving the echo results (including the ones in the if statements)using a success function:

```
echo $upvotetruedownvotefalse;
success: function(response){
          alert(response);
}
```

Then I console.log the result and I would get this:

> Falseyou haven't upvoted yet

I'm getting conflicting results.
I've also tried using different types of `=== !===` in different places and I get either an inverted result or my success function fails

Is there something that I don't know about Boolean operators?
Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing an `echo`, and getting `False` in the output, then it sounds like your variable is holding the string `"False"`, and not the boolean value `false`.  A non-empty string is a "truth-y" value, meaning when you do `if ($some_string)` it will come back true.

Quickest fix would seem to be to add this before the rest of your code:

```
if (strtolower($upvotetruedownvotefalse) === 'false') {
    $upvotetruedownvotefalse = false;
}
//the rest of your code here
```

Comment: sorry I manually typed that part. I'm recieving false not False

Comment: regardless, if you echo a boolean it will come out either "1" if true, or nothing if false.